# How to align the content shown in the image using JavaScript along with redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am bit troubled in aligning the content as shown in the image. Along with that I need to redirect to page 1 by clicking on content section and redirect to page 2 by clicking the icon separately. How can I solve it using javascript?

[image: demo image]

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

These things can be achieved without the use of JavaScript besides the point that it's generally bad practice to manipulate DOM with JavaScript as much can be done with css rules, animations, basic html.
To align the icon first you should try these css rules applied on icon element:

```
.your-icon {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Assuming your icon in html is declared like this:

```
<img src="foo.img" class="your-icon">
```

Although it depends on current rules applied (e.g. you should use other rule set if flex is enabled on parent element). Perhaps spacing with fixed values between content section is involved that is pushing the icon out of the way (padding, margin rules applied?).

As for navigation [html href](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) is good enough

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a {
  /*   width:400px; */
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.b {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /*   border:1px solid red; */
}
.c {
  width: 70%;
  /*   border:1px solid; */
  float: left;
  /*   display:flex; */
  float: left;
  
}
.c div{padding: 5px;}
.d {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.box {
  width: 29%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
}
.rTable {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.rTableHeading,
.rTableBody,
.rTableFoot,
.rTableRow {
  clear: both;
}
.rTableHead,
.rTableFoot {
  /*    background-color: #DDD; */
  font-weight: bold;
}
.rTableCell,
.rTableHead {
  /*    border: 1px solid #999999; */
  float: left;
  height: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 20%;
}
.rTable:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    <div class='c'>
      <div>Name</div>
      <div>Address</div>
      <div>PIN</div>
    </div>
    <div class='box'>ICON</div>
  </div>
  <div class='d'>
    <div class="rTable">
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Time</strong></div>
        <div class="rTableHead"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Duration</span></div>
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Amount</strong></div>
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Position</strong></div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableCell">5</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">2</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">4</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```